# Where to look up argument for a function in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, optional-arguments

For instance,

```
(q_5)   edge    [loop above]        node {a}            (q_5)
```

This is Automaton package, the one I want to look up is `[loop above]`, I want to know what other options can I put in there. I know there are:

- `[bend left]`
- `[bend right]`
- `[loop above]`
- `[loop below]`

I checked at http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/state-machine/ but all I found were just examples :(. There are no manual or reference to look up optional arguments..., I guess there must be one, but somehow I couldn't find them. So where can I find these documents?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `automata` package is part of the TikZ/PGF system and is documented in the PGF manual (Section 24 of the manual for PGF2.10).

The loops are actually provided as part of the `to` library which is documented in Section 51.4 of that manual.